# Unable to rotate instances individually in Geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, vector

I have instanced 14 triangles in a circle mesh. I am trying to rotate these independently of each other, making them point inwards into the circle, or outwards, pointing away from the middle of the circle, dependent on inputs I was planning to add later.

I don't understand why they at least do not point in a different direction using the node tree below. According to the viewer node the "Rotation instance" node should be receiving an array of different vectors, and according to my understanding, each instance should rotate the number in the array with the equivalent index.

The math might be wrong, and I may have to fix it later but one step at a time.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: please provide blend file so we don't have to rebuild everything manually

Answer (score 4):

I recomended to use "curve circle" node instead of "mesh circle" node, and "curve to points" node for giving correct rotation to all triangles. In the examples below you can rotate triangles inward or outward simply by changing "Y" rotation vector in "transform" node.

**Example 1. All outward.**
[image]
**Example 2. All inward.**
[image]
**Example 3. Every 'N' inward. And every 'N+1' outward.**
[image]
**Example 4. Linear from inward to outward.**
[image]
The main mistake of your node setup probably is in wrong placing of "capture attribute" node. It always should be in one line with the nodes where you are going to apply it to.
[image]

Comment: `0` converts to Boolean *False*, and non-zero values convert to Boolean *True*, therefore when you do *modulo 2*, and you know it returns only either `0` or `1`, you can pass it to *Selection* directly - at least until you go beyond `16777216` https://i.imgur.com/pKXzma6.png - but as long as you use float modulo, the *equal* node won't help with it and the result is same with this setup https://i.imgur.com/qO4lbx5.png

Answer (score 1):

Since you're rotating the instances, and you haven't used the *Realize Instances* node, the *Attribute Capture* node is unnecessary. Instead, you can just use the *Position* node, as shown below:
[image]
You also don't need the *To Degrees* node, since all nodes calculated in radians, even though sliders use degrees.