# Align Rotation of Instances to Instancer Normals

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm working on a geo node setup, and I'm stuck on the following problem:

The Z rotation of the runes should be aligned to the normals of the curve circle that's istancing them. An example would e.g. be an engraving on a ring.

[image: This is how it looks right now]

I have tried multiple things, such as

[This](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/246050/rotate-instances-to-align-with-normals)
Or
[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8WRPqpIuMt0)
but those didnt work.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

You should try to connect "Rotation" output from "Curve to Points" node with "Rotation" input from "Instance on Points" node.

[image]

Here is my more complex answer for very similar question:

[Unable to rotate instances individually in Geometry nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/244332/unable-to-rotate-instances-individually-in-geometry-nodes)

And here are several other questions and answers about rotating something along curve:

[Geometry Nodes - rotate point along curve tangent](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/227046/geometry-nodes-rotate-point-along-curve-tangent/250381#250381)

[Align object along curve (Geometry Node 3.0)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/244845/align-object-along-curve-geometry-node-3-0)

[Accessing "n+1"th point instance in geometry node](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/242619/accessing-n1th-point-instance-in-geometry-node/242623#242623)

Comment: Alas I have only one like to give. Thank you for this answer