# How can I set instances to fan out around a point in geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances

I would like to build a snowflake using Geometry Nodes. I have one branch of the snowflake ready and have made instances to rotate them all around the same anchor point. This is how far I have gotten. I'm having trouble getting the instances to line up correctly with this.

[image]
[image]

Thanks in advance for your help!

[image]

Comment: Try to simply plug the input node `Normal` into the input *Vector* of the node `Align Euler to Vector`, but without taking over the *Rotation* of the node `Object Info`...This question has been asked here many times in different variations. Tip: Use the search function and I am sure you will find some good examples.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked!! :)

Comment: You are welcome! PS: This post might also be helpful (there are different ways to reach the goal here): https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/252034/